# Jquery Validation Basics

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, jquery-validate

I asked a pretty tough question on Jquery Validation earlier on, and nobody seems able to answer it, so I am just going to go for the more basic how-to question...
Say I have a form (MVC2 asp.net form might I add), one textbox, on textbox with DateTime in it and one radio button (the values of the Radio Button are Yes or No).  How do I get simple custom validation on those Form Elements if I know the name of the form elements?

Keep in mind these elements are going to be generated Dynamically and so are there validation rules... I am for now just hoping to fudge it a little bit and put permanent validation in there...

I am a complete Jquery and Javascript nooob... All I have ever done with either programming language was add simple tools into my code...

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I get simple custom validation on those Form Elements if I know the name of the form elements?

The [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) contains many examples of how to setup the plugin. Here's an example with static rules:

```
$('#myform').validate({
    rules: {
        Name: { 
            required: true
        },
        DateOfBirth: {
            required: true,
            date: true
        },
        IsMajor: {
            required: true
        }
    }
});
```

and if you wanted to dynamically add those rules you could do this:

```
$('#myform').validate();
```

and then dynamically add rules to individual form elements:

```
$('#Name').rules('add', {
    required: true
});

$('#DateOfBirth').rules('add', {
    required: true,
    date: true
});

$('#IsMajor').rules('add', {
    required: true
});
```

Comment: This looks like about what I have seen so far...  But what is #name... is that the name of the form element?  
So it would be a textbox named name, textbox named DateOfBirth, textBox IsMajor?
What about radio button validation?  Lets say I have a radio button that could be either "yes", "no"  And it has to be one of those two?  How can I validate that?

Comment: @DmainEvent, in the first case with the static rules Name, DateOfBirth, IsMajor correspond to the **name** attribute of the input field. In the second example when rules are applied dynamically, `#Name` is an id selector in jQuery which means that it will look for an element with `id="Name"`. You could replace it with a name selector like this `$('input[name="Name"]')`.

Comment: This is gonna sound so noobtastic, but how would I get a .net string into the jquery validation rules section?  Lets say  I have a form element whose Id is element0?  lets say if that element is empty, I would display a message saying "element0 is null, value must be present".  Again, totally noob tastic, but is there a way I could loop through those elements and set the rule and the message dynamically?  Maybe this is just crazy and I should just write a massive static jquery statement.  thanks.

Comment: @DmainEvent, I wouldn't use a string on the .NET side. I would use a strongly typed object. An array representing elements and rules. Then I would serialize this object into JSON and pass it to javascript. Now on the client side it is a simple matter of looping through the objects of this javascript array and generating the rules dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to know the `id` of the element as long as you assign it to the proper `class`, e.g. the built-in "`required`". Set the class and everything else is taken care of.